# Difference between Keras model.save() and model.save_weights()?

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, neural-network, keras

To save a model in Keras, what are the differences between the output files of:

1. `model.save()`
2. `model.save_weights()`
3. `ModelCheckpoint()` in the callback

The saved file from `model.save()` is larger than the model from `model.save_weights()`, but significantly larger than a JSON or Yaml model architecture file.  Why is this?

Restating this: Why is size(model.save()) + size(something) = size(model.save_weights()) + size(model.to_json()), what is that "something"?

Would it be more efficient to just `model.save_weights()` and `model.to_json()`, and load from these than to just do `model.save()` and `load_model()`?

What are the differences?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

`save()` saves the weights and the model structure to a single `HDF5` file. I believe it also includes things like the optimizer state. Then you can use that HDF5 file with `load()` to reconstruct the whole model, including weights.

`save_weights()` only saves the weights to HDF5 and nothing else. You need extra code to reconstruct the model from a `JSON` file.

Comment: Just wanted a clarification, Using `h5dump --contents` I compared the saved model against the saved weights, and I can see that the weights is just a "group" within the model hd5 file. However there is also the optimiser state. But I don't see any file relating to the model architecture. What is the optimiser state for and how is the model architecture persisted?

Comment: @CMCDragonkai That is not a clarification but a new question.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro Would you care to explain why one would like to save the state of the optimizer? What could go wrong from just loading the weights when trying to keep training the same model, but in a different session (closing python and continuing training some other day, for example).

Comment: @payne Optimizers have state, such as the running means of gradients, so if you start from scratch, learning could be unstable or even fail.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro so using `model.save_weights('my_model_weights.h5')` will mess with the learning process and one should use `model.save('my_model.h5')` in order to pick up training where it was left off ?

Answer (score 9):

- `model.save_weights()`: Will only save the weights so if you need, you are able to apply them on a different architecture
- `mode.save()`: Will save the architecture of the model + the the weights + the training configuration + the state of the optimizer

Comment: [doc](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/Checkpoint#:~:text=Object%2Dbased%20checkpointing%20saves%20a,%2Don%2Dcreate%20for%20variables.) *This function differs slightly from the Keras Model save_weights function. from  tf.keras.Model.save_weights creates a checkpoint file with the name specified in filepath, while tf.train.Checkpoint numbers the checkpoints, using filepath as the prefix for the checkpoint file names. Aside from this, model.save_weights() and tf.train.Checkpoint(model).save() are equivalent.*  but your answer is different.

Answer (score 5):

Just to add what ModelCheckPoint's output is, if it's relevant for anyone else: used as a callback during model training, it can either save the whole model or just the weights depending on what state the `save_weights_only` argument is set to. TRUE and weights only are saved, akin to calling `model.save_weights()`. FALSE (default) and the whole model is saved, as in calling `model.save()`.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the answers above, as of tf.keras version '2.7.0', the model can be saved in 2 formats using model.save() i.e., the TensorFlow SavedModel format, and the older Keras H5 format. The recommended format is SavedModel and it is the default when `model.save()` is called. To save to .h5(HDF5) format, use `model.save('my_model', save_format='h5')` [More](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/save_and_serialize)