# model save in keras json file

Tags: keras, conv-neural-network

I saw the two different kinds of model saving style in Keras.

```
   model.save(os.path.join(model_path, Filename))
```

and other one uses json and weight

```
model_json = model1.to_json()
with open("model1.json", "w") as json_file:
    json_file.write(model_json)
model1.save_weights("model1.h5")
print("Saved model to disk")
```

what is the differens between those two different models?

Comment: Question answered at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42621864/what-are-the-differences-between-keras-model-save-and-model-save-weights?rq=1