# i can load my deep model in colab bu when i want load that model in pc i can't

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I trained a deep model in colab by keras=2.3.1 and tensorflow=2.1.0, I saved my model with JSON and Keras:

```
saveWeightPath = "/content/drive/My Drive/model_info/model_weights.h5"
saveModelPath = "/content/drive/My Drive/model_info"
model.save_weights(saveWeightPath)
tf.keras.models.save_model(model, saveModelPath)
```

and my cose for saved json

```
model_json = model.to_json()
with open("model.json", "w") as json_file:
json_file.write(model_json)
model.save_weights("model.h5")
print("Saved model to disk")
```

when I want load model in colab I don't have a problem but when I want to load my model in pc local I can't and I get this error:
"

- **fid = h5f.open(name, flags, fapl=fapl) File "h5py_objects.pyx", line 54, in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper File "h5py_objects.pyx",
  line 55, in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper File "h5py\h5f.pyx", line
  88, in h5py.h5f.open OSError: Unable to open file (unable to open
  file: name = 'C:/Users/Kosar 37638090/Desktop/end pro/model_info',
  errno = 13, error message = 'Permission denied', flags = 0, o_flags =
  0)**

"

1. my Keras and tensor version is the same as my colab Keras and tensor version
2. I try to load my model with JSON and Keras in pc
3. I get a traceback error and I copy The last 5 lines of the error message and the top lines here3

   [image: top lines of error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi first of all do you need to store your model or your model weights?
To know the difference between that, `model.save()` save you weights and structure model and ... but `model.save_weights()` just save your weight model, I suggest you see this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42621864/difference-between-keras-model-save-and-model-save-weights#:%7E:text=save()%20saves%20the%20weights,to%20a%20single%20HDF5%20file.&text=Then%20you%20can%20use%20that,model%20from%20a%20JSON%20file.) for more information.

If you want to save the model, I suggest using `model.save("test.hd5")` or `model.save(test.hdf5")` and use `tensorflow.kears.models.load_model("test.hd5")` to load the model.