# OSerror: loading a h5 saved model in tensorflow keras after updating the environment in anaconda on windows with python 3.7

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, anaconda, h5py

I am recieving an OSerror (withouth any other text) from h5py when loading an h5 model created with keras- tensorflow after updating my enviroment, or working with an up-to-date environment.

I trained some models with keras and tf in the older versions, and also with keras-tf v1.15 and saved them using the `model.save('filename.h5')` code. Afterwards i am able to load them and work with them further using before the `keras.load_model`, and now `tensorflow.keras.models.load_model` without any problems but recieving some warnings that my tf version was not compiled to use the avx2 instructions and so.
The version installed is tensorflow 1.15 using pip install tensorflow-cpu and it seems to work well, my enviroment installed is Anaconda3-2020.02-Windows-x86_64 installed from the anaconda binaries on Windows.

After trying to change the packages to tensorflow-mkl, and needing to update my enviroment because of enviromental conflicts (shows even with the fresh install of anaconda) the OSerror raised by h5py appears.

Using the default enviromental packages from the anaconda binary with tf-cpu seems to work fine, either by cloning the environment. When updating the environment with `conda update --all` it raises the error either with tfc-cpu or tf-mkl.

The version of h5py in both cases is: '2.10.0' and the error is the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\Oscar\bwSyncAndShare\OPT_PV22WP_intern\pv2wp_control\SIM\Sim_future.py", line 88, in <module>
    model = load_model(pathfile_model)

  File "C:\Users\Oscar\anaconda3\envs\optimizer2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\saving\save.py", line 142, in load_model
    isinstance(filepath, h5py.File) or h5py.is_hdf5(filepath))):

  File "C:\Users\Oscar\anaconda3\envs\optimizer2\lib\site-packages\h5py\_hl\base.py", line 44, in is_hdf5
    return h5f.is_hdf5(filename_encode(fname))

  File "h5py\_objects.pyx", line 54, in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper

  File "h5py\_objects.pyx", line 55, in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper

  File "h5py\h5f.pyx", line 156, in h5py.h5f.is_hdf5

OSError
```

Have anyone had this problem?

- I have tried training a model with the updated environment and saving
  it, when loading i get the same error.
- Updating to tf-cpu v2.3.1
  with the base environment and loading works also.
- Creating a new env, with `conda create -n name python==3.7.x anaconda`
  and then installing tf, doesn´t work.

i think then some other library is making the problem, but i cannot figure out what is the problem.

Comment: well, i seemed to find a solution and it was to downgrade the hdf5 library from v1.10.6  to version 1.10.4 using: conda install hdf5== 1.10.4, this downgraded the lbrary and superseeded the h5py library for another one. Now it seems to load the model as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I use hd5 instead of h5 as the extension,and solve the problem.

[i can load my deep model in colab bu when i want load that model in pc i can't](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63951740/i-can-load-my-deep-model-in-colab-bu-when-i-want-load-that-model-in-pc-i-cant)